# Prestashop Paypal Pro Module

Tags: paypal, integration, prestashop

I want to setup Paypal such that user does not leave my site and can purchase using her credit card.

I tried the Prestashop Paypal Pro Plugin. But it seems it is only for US and Australia. I am in none of these countries.

Then I tried to setup the normal Prestashop Paypal Plugin. In the process of setting up, there is advertisement on solutions that help "Accept Credit Card Payments Today!". Such solutions are:

[PayPal Payments Standard](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/referral/paypal-payments-standard?partner_id=XYAYGKRUJMJTG), [PayPal Payments Advanced](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/referral/paypal-payments-advanced?partner_id=XYAYGKRUJMJTG) etc.

Yet, how do I set these up with Prestashop? Do I need to create a module for this? Or does something already exist?

Answer (score 2):

Try PayPal Pro (Direct Payment) from presto-changeo.com (http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/payment-modules/88-paypal-pro-direct-payment.html)